# <link ... > for background not working

Tags: html, css, web

**This question is solved, it was just a missunderstanding, sorry about that I didn't checked in firefox. Mods please close it, as I don't know how to, thank you. Code works!**

Hello I am having a problem in adding background to my page, it's so simple and i don't know if it's an ide problem or an code problem but here is the code:

```
<html>


  <head>

    <title>Webpage</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">

  </head>

<!--    <style>
      body {
        background: red;
      }

    </style>

  </head> -->

  <body>

    Hello
    <strong>Bold</strong><br><br>

    <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a><br><br>
    <ul>

      <span></span>

      <li>hello</li>
      <li>hello2</li>
      <li>hello2</li>

    </ul>

    <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/idypRYR.jpg">

  </body>

</html>
```

css file:

```
body{
  background: #999;
}
```

No I tried to use the same folder as index.html but same thing it does not work, the folder is correct, I triple checked all the spelling, I don't know what is wrong, I am just learning web development.

I am using atom as ide.

Comment: Open the developer console (usually activated with the F12 key), and look for errors. If there are any, update your question.

Comment: Your [code works](https://jsfiddle.net/7ghajLzf/) , just checked it. Try refreshing after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: On Windows, most browsers can do a hard refresh (thereby reloading all CSS stylesheets) by pressing Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's a useful shortcut

Answer (score -1):

I used your exact code, and it worked for me. This means that it is not a problem with your code. I suggest checking and then double checking your file names. Also, make sure that you are editing/ using the same file that you are viewing.

A second thing that you can do is check to make sure that your css file is actually a css file, as in check the file extension.

A third, and final thing that you can do is that if you are using Chrome, open up developer tools and click on the "sources" tab. If the main.css file is listed there, it is linked correctly and there is a problem with the code, that you didn't show in your post. Otherwise, keep on trying.

Comment: Um, dude he said he already triple checked the spelling.  Besides that, he would have to be a person with a day's worth of experience to miss the file extension step.  Finally, he doesn't have to go to the developer tools to see if it is linked correctly.  All he has to do is Google how to properly link a CSS file.  Overall, your answer was very poorly thought out (which is why I down-voted it).

Comment: LOL

He said, in his post, that he is just leaning web development.

Comment: Dude.  Do you not get what I'm saying?

Comment: Ok, sorry that was a little mean.

Comment: But seriously dude?

Comment: Also, he did properly link his CSS file using the <link> tag. If it isn't working, Googling how to link a CSS isn't going to help him. However, if he checks which files are linked, he can tell if there is a problem with the HTML or the CSS.

Comment: I am just telling you what is wrong with your darn question.  I'm giving you tips on how to properly answer questions in the future.  Honestly, you should thank me.

Comment: I use atom and html preview package I ll check since it works for you

Comment: It indeed does work, ok i didn't cosider that, Please close it thank you!